# Java (Android) - ProgressDialog appears twice

Tags: java, android, android-activity, progressdialog

I have a problem with ProgressDialog. In init() method i have progressDialog.show(), but inside that method I'm using two background task methods, which after load are going to progressDialog.dismiss(), but then the progressDialog is showing again and looping for ever. What to do?

```
ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog;


    @AfterViews
    void init() {
        //launch ProgressDialog
        ringProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ringProgressDialog.setMessage("Ładowanie rozkładów\nz najbliższej stacji");
        ringProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        if(!ringProgressDialog.isShowing())
            ringProgressDialog.show();

        restBackgroundTrainLeft.getTrains(closestStation.id, endStationLeft.id, currentHour);
        restBackgroundTrainRight.getTrains(closestStation.id, endStationRight.id, currentHour);

    }




    //region after BACKGROUND TASK METHODS
    public void updateTrainsLeft(TrainsList trainsList){
        if(trainsList != null){
            adapterLeft.update(trainsList);
        }

        if(ringProgressDialog.isShowing())
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void updateTrainsRight(TrainsList trainsList){
        if(trainsList != null) {
            adapterRight.update(trainsList);
        }

       if(ringProgressDialog.isShowing())
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
//endregion
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of problem though it not fully matching.
I solved this like that-
I initialize progress Dialog checking null.

```
if (ringProgressDialog == null){
    ringProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
ringProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
ringProgressDialog.show();
```

and during dismiss-

```
if (ringProgressDialog != null && ringProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
       ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
   }
```